# Why is the `Clone` trait not implemented for `fn(&T)`?

Tags: rust

The following code does not work because the `Clone` trait is not implemented for the type `fn(&u16)`:

```
#[derive(Clone)]
struct FStruct(fn(&u16));

fn fn1(x:&u16){
    println!("fn1 called! {:?}", x);
}

fn fn2(x:&u16){
    println!("fn2 called! {:?}", x);
}

fn main() {

    let d1 = 32u16;
    let d2 = 42u16;

    let x1 = FStruct(fn1);
    let mut x2 = FStruct(fn2);

    x1.0(&d1); x2.0(&d2);

    x2 = x1.clone();//error: the trait `core::clone::Clone` is not implemented for the type `fn(&u16)`

    x1.0(&d1); x2.0(&d2);
}
```

I can implement it by myself of course:

```
impl Clone for FStruct{
    fn clone(&self) -> Self{
        unsafe{
            let mut t: FStruct = std::mem::uninitialized();
            std::ptr::copy_nonoverlapping(self, &mut t, 1);
            t      
        }
    }
}
```

But it is a bit annoying. Rust allows implementing `Clone` only for user types, so I need a struct or enum around `fn(&T)`.

Is this implementation really safe to use? Why is `Clone` not implemented for `fn(&T)` by default?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The "why" is pretty simple: [issue 28229](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/28229) wasn't fixed until [Rust 1.21.0](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/RELEASES.md#version-1210-2017-10-12). Since that version, your code compiles.

Before that, due to a quirk of history, `fn` pointers *do* implement `Copy`, even though they don't implement `Clone` (and despite this being *blatantly impossible*).  As a result, you *can* do this:

```rust
impl Clone for FStruct {
    fn clone(&self) -> Self {
        FStruct(self.0)
    }
}
```

Which is safe and easier to understand.

Comment: … and so if you pass a `fn(&i16)` to a function taking `T: Copy` which proceeds to try to clone it, you get an “``error: internal compiler error: Encountered error `Unimplemented` selecting `Binder(<fn(&i16) as core::clone::Clone>)` during trans``” Fun!